# Чем отличается @Controller от @RestController кроме того что RestController содержит @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, controller

И да меня подбешивает когда говорят что если не знаешь чем отличается RestController от Controller Другое можно не спрашивать. Потому что в Спринге столько тонкостей что голова идёт кругом.
Ещё говориться что Сontroller управляет моделями, а RestController - данными. Что это значит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная разница между `@Controller` и `@RestController` заключается в способе создания тела HTTP ответа. Если класс имеет аннотацию `@Controller`, то его методы-обработчики без `@ResponseBody` возвращают строку (`String`) - название представления, которое надо показать пользователю. Методы-обработчики с `@ResponseBody` могут иметь любой тип возвращаемого значения.

`@RestController` по сути объединяет в себе эти две аннотации, и соответственно методы класса, помеченного данной аннотацией могут иметь любой тип возвращаемого значения.

`Controller` является частью MVC. Если вкратце - Controller взаимодействует с моделью, получает из неё какие-то данные и затем отображает их в представлении.

`RestController` используется для создания RESTfull веб-сервисов. Он взаимодействует с какими-либо данными и возвращает объект, который представляется в HTTP ответе  в виде JSON или XML.